# Local function becomes global after Plot

Tags: scoping

In the code below, I define and plot a local function `f`.

```
Clear[f]
Module[{f}, f[x_] := 1; Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 1}]]
```

However, after evaluation, `?f` reveals that the definition of `f` has become global. Why is this so?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: anon, welcome.  Your question has been asked and answered before.  Please see the link in the banner inserted at the top of your post.

Answer (score 1):

Nasser is correct that the symbol name `f` appears to have leaked out of `Module`.  However, I believe that this causes no harm, because it actually is a distinct symbol from that in the Module:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]; Remove["Global`*"];

(* Remove::rmnsm: There are no symbols matching "Global`*". >> *)

Module[{f}, f[x_] := 1; {Information[f], Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 1}]}]

(* Global`f$1433
      Attributes[f$1433]={Temporary} 
  f$1433[x_]:=1
followed by the plot *)

Information[f]

(* Global`f *)
```

Comment: Are you sure about this? How about this: `ClearAll["Global`*"]
Remove["Global`*"];
Module[{f = 0}, 0];` and now type `?f` you'll see it in the global symbol table. How can this be explained? Since `f` now is just symbol inside a Module? but notice only the symbol is leaked. It has no value in Global, only its name is entered.

Comment: @Nasser I see your point.  Certainly, there are two different `f`s, but, perhaps, I am answering the wrong question.  I need to think about this.  Thanks.

Comment: @Nasser Thanks.  This is more subtle than I had supposed.

Comment: @Nasser and bbgodfrey, the ``Global`f`` is created during parsing.  See my answer to the marked duplicate for reference.